# Tyring to figure out ip-route

Tags: routing, cisco, ip-routing

I've been playing with packet tracer and trying to fully grasp ip routing. So far I'm doing ok i think.

Why am i able to ping r3 from pc1 (route working correctly as it should) vice-versa but **cant** ping r3 from r1.

[image: Network Route]

Comment: We can't tell you without seeing the configurations (or at least the route tables) from the devices.  Please edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess R3 don't know the "network 1" (subnet between R1 and R2).
When R1 sends the icmp echo request (ping) it will use the IP address of the interface that the packet uses to exit the router as a source, in this case, the IP of the interface connected to "network 1".

from R1, try extended ping using the IP of the interface connected to Network2.

here you can find details about extended ping:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13730-ext-ping-trace.html

If the issue persists, could you please share the configuration of R1, R2, and R3?

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for this. This was exactly the case

Answer (score 0):

So, I've redrawn your topology.

[image]

Let's assume on the `PC1` the network interface has name `PC1-N1-IF` with assigned address `PC1-N1-IP`. On the `R1` router the network interface connected to the `NTWRK1` has name `R1-N1-IF` with address `R1-N1-IP`. And so on.

After assignment of addresses to interfaces the routing tables on the devices will looks like:

- `PC1`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK1, iface <PC1-N1-IF>`
- `R1`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK1, iface <R1-N1-IF>`
  - `directly-connected NTWRK2, iface <R1-N2-IF>`
- `R2`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK2, iface <R2-N2-IF>`
  - `directly-connected NTWRK3, iface <R2-N3-IF>`
- `R3`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK3, iface <R3-N3-IF>`
  - `directly-connected NTWRK4, iface <R3-N4-IF>`
- `PC2`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK3, iface <PC2-N3-IF>`
- `PC3`:

  - `directly-connected NTWRK4, iface <PC3-N2-IF>`

To get the full connectivity in your topology you need:

- `PC1`:

  - Add default route via `R1`: `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <R1-N1-IP>`
- `R1`:

  - Add route to `NTWRK3` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK3> <R2-N2-IP>`
  - Add route to `NTWRK4` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK4> <R2-N2-IP>`
- `R2`:

  - Add route to `NTWRK1` via `R1`: `ip route <NTWRK1> <R1-N2-IP>`
  - Add route to `NTWRK4` via `R3`: `ip route <NTWRK4> <R3-N3-IP>`
- `PC2`:

  - Add route to `NTWRK1` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK1> <R2-N3-IP>`
  - Add route to `NTWRK2` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK2> <R2-N3-IP>`
  - Add route to `NTWRK4` via `R3`: `ip route <NTWRK4> <R3-N3-IP>`
- `R3`:

  - Add route to `NTWRK1` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK1> <R2-N3-IP>`
  - Add route to `NTWRK2` via `R2`: `ip route <NTWRK2> <R2-N3-IP>`
- `PC3`:

  - Add default route via `R3`: `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <R3-N4-IP>`

We use simplest configuration without recursive routes and address aggregation. Try to determine how the routing table will look after adding the routes on some device.

Additional readings:

- The computer networks by Tanenbaum
- Cisco CCNA book

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check those books out